# Is there any way to find my iPhone

Tags: iphone

I lost my iPhone. I connected this iPhone to my iCloud, but I can't get this phone. That phone not having GPS on and Data Pack. Is there any way to find this? Is there any possibility to use this phone?

Comment: Does the phone show up in Find my iPhone on [iCloud](http://icloud.com)?

Comment: Yes. But its in offline.

Comment: Check out [this Apple Support article](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204233). Should help you

Answer (score 1):

**From Apple Support:**

> If you see "Offline," "No location available," or "Location Services Off," your device might be offline for one of these reasons:
>
> - It's powered off, the battery has run out, or it’s been more than 24 hours since the last location was sent to Apple (if Send Last Location is turned on). When your device is connected to the Internet, you can see the remaining battery in the upper-right corner of the information pane.
> - Your iPad, iPod Touch, or Mac is asleep and not connected to a known
>     Wi-Fi or data network. Wait a few minutes and try again.
> - You're in a country where we don't offer this feature. This feature
>     might not be available in your country due to technical limitations
>     or local law.
>
> You can still play a sound, send a message, issue a lock request, or start an erase of your iOS device with Find My iPhone. Your device will receive the command after it's turned on and has an Internet connection.